# Order By Not Working in a double select query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the latest message of each user; it should group multiple messages that has the same User ID which is From another ID **fromUserId**

This is the query that returns multiple messages from a same user; it should Sort messages in a descending order through its **ID** but the query is **not sorting** them out. It should display them in a descending order which is 3, 2, 1....

```
SELECT DATA.* FROM (
SELECT a.*, b.firstName, b.middleName, b.lastName FROM `users_messages` a LEFT JOIN `users` b ON b.id = a.fromUserId 
WHERE a.toUserId = '2' ORDER BY a.id DESC) DATA
```

[Here is a screenshot of the first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIw6v.png)

So I tried grouping them up from the User ID **fromUserID** and the results is 1 and 3, it should return 2 and 3 since 2 is the latest message of the user ID 3

```
SELECT DATA.* FROM (
SELECT a.*, b.firstName, b.middleName, b.lastName FROM `users_messages` a LEFT JOIN `users` b ON b.id = a.fromUserId 
WHERE a.toUserId = '2' ORDER BY a.id DESC) DATA GROUP BY DATA.fromUserId
```

[Here is a screenshot of the second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRZS9.png)

Comment: Using `SELECT DATA.* .... GROUP BY DATA.formUserId` is a invalid ANSI SQL query. On MySQL it will execute but can deliver invalid results. ( https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ )

Comment: Is there any other way to group data and get its latest data through query only?

Comment: Would you like to add sample data and expected output as text to your question?

Comment: @P.Salmon Here is a sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c06736/3/0 it should group them by "fromUserId" and display the latest id of each message "fromUserId", expected output should display 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub query to get the latest message fromuserid/touserid

```
SELECT id,touserid,fromuserid,message,date
FROM users_messages um
where id = (select max(um1.id) from users_messages um1 where um1.touserid = um.touserid and um1.fromuserid = um.fromuserid) 
order by id desc

+------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id   | touserid | fromuserid | message                              | date                |
+------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
|    3 |        2 |          4 | Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello  | 2018-02-05 21:37:29 |
|    2 |        2 |          3 | Test 2                               | 2018-02-05 21:37:25 |
+------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```